# How to return string from sp pnp js request?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, pnp-js-core

I need help with how I can return a string from a SP PnP js request?

I want to display the string `displayName` in the console log on the last line. The `result.Title` is a string.

```
public static GetUserDisplayNameById(Id: number) {
    return pnp.sp.site.rootWeb
        .getUserById(Id)
        .select("Title")
        .get()
        .then(result => {
            return result.Title;
        });
}

let UserDisplayName = Utility.GetUserDisplayNameById(13);
console.log(UserDisplayName);
```

But this is what gets displayed in the console:

```
Promise {<pending>}
{
    [[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved",
    [[PromiseValue]]: "Saad Humayun"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetUserDisplayNameById` returns `Promise` so you have to use `.then()`.

```
public static GetUserDisplayNameById(Id: number) {
    return pnp.sp.site.rootWeb
        .getUserById(Id)
        .select("Title")
        .get()
        .then(result => {
            return result.Title;
        });
}

Utility.GetUserDisplayNameById(13).then(UserDisplayName => {
    console.log(UserDisplayName);
});
```

Or you can convert it to [async/await pattern](https://javascript.info/async-await).

```
public static async GetUserDisplayNameById(Id: number) {
    const result = await pnp.sp.site.rootWeb
        .getUserById(Id)
        .select("Title")
        .get();
    return result.Title;
}

const UserDisplayName = await Utility.GetUserDisplayNameById(13);
console.log(UserDisplayName);
```

Comment: Thanks, async/await pattern solved my problem.